# Create and toggle Windows Firewall rule

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, autohotkey

Using a single batch, PowerShell or AHK script, how can I:

1. (if it does not exist) create a Windows Firewall rule that blocks a program; and
2. disables or enables the rule depending on what its current state is?

Answer (score 2):

**Using PowerShell** (>= Version 4.0)

For more details read these links:
[New-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=winserver2012-ps)
[Manage Windows Firewall with Powershell](https://letitknow.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/manage-windows-firewall-with-powershell-3/)

A template to generate your own new rule (adapt your parameters):

```
#Requires -Version 4.0
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram `
    -Program "C:\Path\To\YourProgram.exe" `
    -Action Block `
    -Profile Domain, Private `
    -Description "Demonstration" `
    -Protocol TCP `
    -Direction Outbound
```

To enable/disable the rule

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram -Enabled True
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram -Enabled False
```

to toggle the rule

```
if ((Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram).Enabled){
     Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram -Enabled False
} Else {
     Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockYourProgram -Enabled True
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error `The term 'New-NetFirewallRule' is not recognized...`

Comment: What PowerShell Version are you using?

Comment: 2.0 (Windows 7).

Comment: I'm sorry `New-NetFireWallRule` was introduced with  `Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1` and require these Version or newer. I don't know if it is sufficient to update PowerShell.